# SwiftUI Animation Doesn't Always Run

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I'm working on some code to teach myself SwiftUI, and my current project is a dice roller app.

In my view, I present some images using SFSymbols to represent the value of each die after the roll.  I use two animations (`.rotation3Deffect` and `.rotationEffect`) on each image to give a visual roll of the dice.

I have found that the animations will only run if the individual die value (or in case of the code, if the `Image(systemName: "\(diceValue).square.fill")`) changes from one roll to the next.  In other words, if I roll three dice, and they land on 1-4-6, then I roll again and they land on 1-4-7, the 1 and 4 images will perform the animation, but the image changing from 6 to 7 does not animate - it just updates to the new image.  Any idea why the animation only runs on the images that did not change from the previous dice roll?

```
import SwiftUI
struct Dice {
    var sides: Int
    var values: [Int] {
        var calculatedValues = [Int]()
        for v in 1...sides {
            calculatedValues.append(v)
        }
        return calculatedValues
    }
    
    func rollDice() -> Int {
        
        let index = Int.random(in: 0..<values.count)
        return values[index]
    }
}

struct Roll: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
     var diceNumber: Int = 0
     var diceValue: Int = 0
}

struct DiceThrow: Hashable {
    var rolls = [Roll]()
    
    var totalScore: Int {
        var score = 0
        for roll in rolls {
            score += roll.diceValue
        }
        return score
    }
}

class ThrowStore: ObservableObject, Hashable {
    @Published var diceThrows = [DiceThrow]()
    
    static func ==(lhs: ThrowStore, rhs: ThrowStore) -> Bool {
        return lhs.diceThrows == rhs.diceThrows
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(diceThrows)
    }
}

class Settings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dicePerRoll: Int = 1
    @Published var sidesPerDice: Int = 4
    
    init(dicePerRoll: Int, sidesPerDice: Int) {
        self.dicePerRoll = dicePerRoll
        self.sidesPerDice = sidesPerDice
    }
    
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var throwStore = ThrowStore()
    let settings = Settings(dicePerRoll: 3, sidesPerDice: 6)
    @State private var roll = Roll()
    @State private var diceThrow = DiceThrow()
    @State private var isRotated = false
    @State private var rotationAngle: Double = 0
    var animation: Animation {
        Animation.easeOut(duration: 3)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if self.throwStore.diceThrows.count != 0 {
                HStack {
                    Text("For dice roll #\(self.throwStore.diceThrows.count)...")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.leading)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            List {
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Spacer()
                    ForEach(diceThrow.rolls, id: \.self) { printedRoll in
                        Text("\(printedRoll.diceValue)")
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4))
                            .rotation3DEffect(Angle.degrees(isRotated ? 3600 : 0), axis: (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))
                            .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(isRotated ? 3600 : 0))
                            .animation(animation)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                if self.throwStore.diceThrows.count != 0 {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Total for this roll:")
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(self.diceThrow.totalScore)")
                            .padding(.leading)
                            .padding(.trailing)
                            .background(Capsule().stroke())
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            Button("Roll the dice") {
                self.diceThrow.rolls = [Roll]()
                self.isRotated.toggle()
                for diceNumber in 1...settings.dicePerRoll {
                    let currentDice = Dice(sides: settings.sidesPerDice)
                    roll.diceNumber = diceNumber
                    roll.diceValue = currentDice.rollDice()
                    
                    self.diceThrow.rolls.append(roll)
                }
                
                self.throwStore.diceThrows.append(self.diceThrow)
                
            }
                .frame(width: 200)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
            .padding(.bottom)
            

        }
    }
    
    func showDiceRoll(_ sides: Int) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have updated the original post with code that can reproduce the problem.  Run it and tap the Roll Dice button multiple times.  You will see that the animations only run when the image is not changed from the previous roll.  My goal is to get the animation to run for each die on each roll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario the data identifiers in `ForEach` should remain the same, otherwise corresponding views are replaced and animation does not work.

The fix for this is simple - use `diceNumber` as ID:

```
ForEach(diceThrow.rolls, id: \.diceNumber) { printedRoll in
    Text("\(printedRoll.diceValue)")
```

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]